# Does the contraction of the tensor with the Kronecker delta always yield the same tensor?

Tags: tensors

Let us consider the $a^{ij}$ tensor, so that $a^{11}=1$; $a^{12}=2$; $a^{21}=3$; $a^{22}=4$.

Let us consider $b^{jl}=a^{ij}\delta_{i}^{~l}$. I think that coordinates of $b_{jl}$ will be: $b^{11}=1$; $b^{12}=3$; $b^{21}=2$; $b^{22}=4$. Am I right?

Thus, by the contraction with the Kronecker delta we may obtain the tensor, that does not coincide with the initial one. Is it correct?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The tensor contraction takes a $(r,s)$ tensor $\mathbf{T}^{i_1,\ldots,i_r}_{j_1,\ldots,j_s}$ and produces a $(r-1,s-1)$ tensor. For your example, you contract the $(3,1)$ tensor $\mathbf{a}^{ij}\mathbf{\delta}^k_\ell$, so you can not really say that you obtain the same tensor after a contraction.

Let us write in local coordinates
$$\mathbf{a}^{ij}=\sum_{1\leq i,j\leq 2}a^{ij}\partial_{x_i}\otimes\partial_{x_j}$$
and
$$\mathbf{\delta}^k_\ell
=\sum_{1\leq k\leq 2}\partial_{x_k}\otimes\mathrm{d}x^{k}\quad\quad\text{(the matrix identity)}$$
where $\mathbf{T}^{ij}$ denotes a tensor and $T^{ij}$ its local coordinates, and $\partial_{x_i}$ and $\mathrm{d}x^{i}$ are respectively the vectors basis of the tangent space and its dual.

We have
$$\mathbf{b}^{ijk}_\ell=\mathbf{a}^{ij}\otimes\mathbf{\delta}^k_\ell=\sum_{1\leq i,j,k,\ell\leq 2}a^{ij}\delta^k_\ell\partial_{x_i}\otimes\partial_{x_j}\otimes\partial_{x_k}\otimes\mathrm{d}x^{\ell}$$
and then
$$\mathbf{b}^{jk}:=\mathbf{b}^{ijk}_i:=\mathcal{C}^1_1\left(\mathbf{a}^{ij}\otimes\mathbf{\delta}^k_i\right):=\sum_{1\leq j,k\leq 2}\sum_{1\leq \alpha\leq 2}a^{\alpha j}\delta^k_\alpha\partial_{x_j}\otimes\partial_{x_k}
=\sum_{1\leq j\leq 2}\sum_{1\leq \alpha\leq 2}a^{\alpha j}\partial_{x_j}\otimes\partial_{x_\alpha}=\left(\mathbf{a}^{jk}\right)^T.$$
More concisely,
$$b^{11}=a^{i1}\delta^{1}_{i}=a^{11}\delta^{1}_{1}=a^{11},$$
$$b^{12}=a^{i1}\delta^{2}_{i}=a^{21}\delta^{2}_{2}=a^{21},$$
$$b^{21}=a^{i2}\delta^{1}_{i}=a^{12}\delta^{1}_{1}=a^{12},$$
$$b^{22}=a^{i2}\delta^{2}_{i}=a^{21}\delta^{2}_{2}=a^{22}.$$

Comment: Is the last equation correct? Should not it be $\mathbf{a}^{ji}$ instead of $\mathbf{a}^{ij}$? Please, note that in the next to last expression the order of indices in $a^{\alpha j}$ and $\partial_{x_j}\otimes\partial_{x_\alpha}$ is different.

Comment: @rtmd You are right, the last tensor is indeed $\mathbf{a}^{ji}$. The last equation is the definition of the contraction on the first covariant and contravariant indices of the tensor $\mathbf{a}^{ij}\mathbf{\delta}^{k}_\ell$.

Comment: @rtmd I have added some notations ; you seem to prefer the index notations, so you may read the last paragraph, that shows why we obtain the transpose of the original tensor - and indeed, we can get a tensor different from the original by this operation.

Comment: Thank you, Nicolas. So my initial idea is confirmed.<br/>The thing that suprised me even more: for a third-order tensor $a^{ijk}$ neither $\delta_{j}^{~m}a^{ijk}$ nor $a^{ijk}\delta_{j}^{~m}$ produce the original tensor. At the same time $a^{ijk}\delta_{k}^{~m}$ yields the initial tensor. So the "behavior" of index depends on whether it is first, last, or middle - that seemed artificial to me.

Comment: I have loosely used the expression "contraction of $a^{ij}$ with $\delta_{k}^{~l}$" instead of formally correct "multiplying $a^{ij}$ by $\delta_{k}^{~l}$ and contraction of the resulting tensor by the indices $j$ and $k$”.

Comment: @rtmd You're right when you say that the tensor contraction depends on the "position" of the indices : this comes from the fact that the tensor product is not commutative. You can actually check that it commutes iff you consider the product of a covariant tensor with a contravariant one, e.g. $a^{ij}b_{i\ell}=b_{i\ell}a^{ij}$.